# How do I get the CLion debugger/console to tell me how many seconds my program took to run?

Tags: c, timing, clion

How do I time my C program in Clion? Is there an option I can use to to tell me how long long my program took to run?

something like

### > *finished in .003 seconds*

here is what I am referring to when I say debugger/console:
[image]

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can measure the time of your code from inside your C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    clock_t start = clock();

    int n = 100; 
    int i=0;
    while(i<100*n)
        i++;

    clock_t stop = clock();
    double elapsed = (double) (stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nTime elapsed: %.5f\n", elapsed);
    return 0;
}
```